# Passing multiple arguments to functions repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am drawing a few overlaid plots, and I want to pass the same arguments to different functions. I'm wondering if this is possible?

For [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

#instead of this
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, color=".25")

#something like this
my_kwargs=(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
ax = sns.boxplot(my_kwargs)
ax = sns.swarmplot(my_kwargs, color=".25")
```

Is something like this possible at all?

I'm aware I can pre-define each of them as a variable, and then specify them inside each function. But I'm wondering if there is something better than this

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there:

```
my_kwargs = dict(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
ax = sns.boxplot(**my_kwargs)
ax = sns.swarmplot(color=".25", **my_kwargs)  # ** must be last
```